# How indispensable are parentheses in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to see if (X ∩ Y) ∩ (X ∪ Y) = (X ∩ Y)

Here's what I have:

(X ∩ Y) ∩ (X ∪ Y) = (X ∩ Y)

(Y ∩ X) ∩ (X ∪ Y) = (X ∩ Y)

(Y ∩ (X ∩ (X ∪ Y)) = (X ∩ Y)

(Y ∩ (X ∩ X) ∪ ( X ∩ Y)) = (X ∩ Y)

(Y ∩ X ∪ ( X ∩ Y)) = (X ∩ Y)

(X ∩ Y ∪ ( X ∩ Y)) = (X ∩ Y)

(X ∩ Y) = (X ∩ Y)

My textbook is more strict about not dropping parentheses. Is the third line application of the Associative Law even allowed? The book jumps straight into a distribution, though that makes it more complicated.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what specific movement you are wanting clarification on since you have a mismatched number of parentheses on several lines and you have not enough parentheses on other lines.

Comment: The end result is that $A\cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap C$ and since there is no confusion between these you can opt to write it as $A\cap B\cap C$ with no ambiguity.  Similarly if both were unions as well.  However, $(A\cap B)\cup C$ is not the same as $A\cap (B\cup C)$ so here we may not drop the parentheses.  $A\cap B\cup C$ is ambiguous and is not allowed.

Comment: As for proving this... $(X\cap Y)\cap (X\cup Y) = ((X\cap Y)\cap X)\cup ((X\cap Y)\cap Y)=(X\cap Y)\cup (X\cap Y)=X\cap Y$.  "*The book jumps straight into a distribution, though that makes it more complicated*"  Not really... just remember that $X\cap Y$ is also a set, and although it happens to take more characters to write than just one all of the same properties and identities still apply to it just like they would apply to any other set written with a single character.

Answer (score 2):

One general consideration is that $A \subset B \Leftrightarrow A \cap B = A $. In your case $A=X \cap Y$ and $B = X \cup Y$.

Second, using logical operations, x belongs to left side gives

$(x \in X \land x \in Y ) \land (x \in X \lor x \in Y) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow(x \in X \land x \in Y \land x \in X) \lor (x \in X \land x \in Y \land x \in Y) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow(x \in X \land x \in Y ) \lor (x \in X \land x \in Y ) \Leftrightarrow \\\Leftrightarrow (x \in X \land x \in Y )$

So x belongs to right side. And because we have equivalence reverse is also correct.

And third, same as above, but using sets:

$(X \cap Y)\cap (X \cup Y) = \\ = ((X \cap Y) \cap X)\cup ((X \cap Y) \cap Y) = \\ = 
((Y \cap X) \cap X)\cup (X \cap (Y \cap Y)) = \\ = (Y \cap (X \cap X))\cup (X \cap (Y \cap Y)) = \\ = (Y \cap X )\cup (X \cap Y ) = \\ =(X \cap Y ) $

From 1 line to 2 distribution, from 2 to 3 associativity and commutativity, from 3 to 4 again  associativity.

Comment: Very cool, I will play it by the book!